# Select rows from array of nested objects and remove rows with some matched columns

Tags: google-bigquery

This is kind of a weirdly specific use case, but I'm struggling to figure out how to only retrieve one row based on some columns within a nested struct, and also remove any subsequent rows that may have the same values. I can't use `SELECT DISTINCT` because some column values within the returned row may differ and `SELECT DISTINCT` would still include them in the results.

The raw data looks something like this:

```sql
WITH order_rates AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST([
    STRUCT(
      1234567890 AS order_id,
      [
        STRUCT(
          "EUR" AS base_currency,
          "USD" AS target_currency,
          0.81 AS rate
        )
      ] AS rates
    ),
    STRUCT(
      1234567891 AS order_id,
      [
        STRUCT(
          "EUR" AS base_currency,
          "CAD" AS target_currency,
          0.78 AS rate
        ),
        STRUCT(
          "EUR" AS base_currency,
          "USD" AS target_currency,
          0.82 AS rate
        )
      ] AS rates
    ),
    STRUCT(
      1234567892 AS order_id,
      [
        STRUCT(
          "EUR" AS base_currency,
          "JPY" AS target_currency,
          0.0071 AS rate
        ),
        STRUCT(
          "EUR" AS base_currency,
          "JPY" AS target_currency,
          0.0074 AS rate
        )
      ] AS rates
    )
  ])
)

SELECT * FROM order_rates
```

```
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------+----------------+
| order_id      | rates.base_currency | rates.target_currency | rates.rate     |
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------+----------------+
| 1234567890    | EUR                 | USD                   | 0.81           |
| 1234567891    | EUR                 | CAD                   | 0.78           |
|               | EUR                 | USD                   | 0.82           |
| 1234567892    | EUR                 | JPY                   | 0.0071         |
|               | EUR                 | JPY                   | 0.0074         |
+---------------+---------------------+-----------------------+----------------+ ​
```

I basically want to turn it into this:

```
+---------------+---------------+-----------------+----------+
| order_id      | base_currency | target_currency | rate     |
+---------------+---------------+-----------------+----------+
| 1234567890    | EUR           | USD             | 0.81     |
| 1234567891    | EUR           | CAD             | 0.78     |
| 1234567891    | EUR           | USD             | 0.82     |
| 1234567892    | EUR           | JPY             | 0.0071   |
+---------------+---------------+-----------------+----------+ ​
```

So far I have this query using `UNNEST(rates) AS rate` which is easy enough:

```sql
WITH order_rates AS (...)

SELECT
  order_id,
  rate.base_currency,
  rate.target_currency,
  rate.rate
FROM order_rates,
  UNNEST(rates) AS rate
```

However it gives me all the rates per order, including extra ones of the same base/target currency pair I don't want:

```
+---------------+---------------+-----------------+----------+
| order_id      | base_currency | target_currency | rate     |
+---------------+---------------+-----------------+----------+
| 1234567890    | EUR           | USD             | 0.81     |
| 1234567891    | EUR           | CAD             | 0.78     |
| 1234567891    | EUR           | USD             | 0.82     |
| 1234567892    | EUR           | JPY             | 0.0071   |
| 1234567892    | EUR           | JPY             | 0.0074   | <-- Need to remove this!
+---------------+---------------+-----------------+----------+​
```

I've been struggling with the issue all day and I can't seem to figure out how to ensure that I only select the first pair of base/target currency and that any subsequent rows with the same `order_id`, `base_currency` and `target_currency` values are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
select
  order_id,
  rate.base_currency,
  rate.target_currency,
  rate.rate
from order_rates,
  unnest(rates) as rate with offset
where true
qualify row_number() over(partition by order_id, base_currency, target_currency order by offset) = 1
```

if applide to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for that! One thing which seemed a bit superfluous was the `where true` part. In my final query I already had a `WHERE` clause, so I just removed the `true` part.